# When I run TIME_TO_SEC to modify a GENERATED column, it throws an error although TIME_TO_SEC works fine independently in a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, alter, generated

I am running the following MySQL script and it throws an error, Could someone tell me what is wrong?

```
"ALTER TABLE class_sessions_archive MODIFY COLUMN session_time_computed int(11) AS TIME_TO_SEC(ends_on-starts_on)"
```

The error message in MySQL remains cryptic, however, I paste it here:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIME_TO_SEC(ends_on-starts_on)' at line 1
```

All I need is to take the difference of two dates and store it in seconds in a new column. I made a new column and now want to modify it.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: You can not alter a column that way. You can alter from datatype to another (compatible) data type: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression should go in parentheses:

```
ALTER TABLE class_sessions_archive
    MODIFY COLUMN session_time_computed int(11) AS (TIME_TO_SEC(ends_on - starts_on));
```

Comment: Damn! that brackets were missed. Thanks a ton @Gordon. 
But now I have another problem which could be a simple extension to this question only. 

While the new column is calculating the time difference in seconds many rows are getting populated as NULL. I checked both dependent columns on which the generated column is calculated and they exist. 

Attached is a screenshot of my MYSQL table [view] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vpn7odz9k2g4hl/Screenshot%202017-08-20%2021.49.25.png?dl=0)

Comment: @sanjmeh. . . New questions should be asked as *new questions* not in comments.  This appears to answer the question that you asked.  The new question should have appropriate sample data and desired results.